# Python Tkinter: Images in canvas cannot show correctly when I wrote it in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a newbie python user.
Today I want to get the validation code of one website and show it on my GUI but meet a problem.
In this code I can get nothing at the position of canvas,but the label and button can show correctly:

```
class Application():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.createWidgets()
def createWidgets(self):
    label = Label(self.root,text='Input this Checkcode')
    label.pack() #show correctly
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.root,width = 500)
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://xxx/ValidateCode')
    image = Image.open(StringIO(response.read()))
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas.create_image(300,50,image = im)
    canvas.pack() # no image
    quitButton = Button(self.root,text='Quit',command=self.root.quit)
    quitButton.pack() #show correctly
if __name__ == '__main__':
app = Application()
app.root.mainloop()
```

But in this one I got the expected result,the only difference is writing the GUI in **main** but not another class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
root = Tkinter.Tk()
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://xxx/ValidateCode')
image = Image.open(StringIO(response.read()))
label = Label(root,text='Input this Checkcode')
label.pack() # show correctly
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root,width = 500)
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(300,50,image = im)
canvas.pack() # show correctly
quitButton = Button(root,text='Quit',command=root.quit)
quitButton.pack() # show correctly
root.mainloop()
```

That's why? I'm really puzzled..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Canvas and other GUI elements into instance variables of `Application`, as in `self.canvas`, `self.label`, etc.  Otherwise they will go out of scope when you leave `createWidgets`.  The reason your **main** example works is because all the variables are are still in scope when `mainloop` is called.